# Why does $P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) − P(E \cap F)$ hold?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In my stochastics book, I saw the following "probability", however, I can't really place it. Can someone explain to me why

$P(E \cup F) = P(E) + P(F) − P(E \cap F)$ (with P meaning the probability) holds?

I know $P(E \cup F)$ means the union of $E$ and $F$, thus, the probability of the outcome being in E, F or both. But why does the equation have the "$-P(E ∩ F)$" part in there? Shouldn't it be $+$?

Comment: The equation is right (the minus should ***not*** be a plus), and it ***always*** holds, well whenever the probabilities are defined.

Comment: By the way, it's not a "definition".

Comment: No you're right, it's the probability of the union, I see. However, I'm still wondering how this probability is set up

Comment: I see it now, thank you, the last part, $−P(E∩E)$ is a intersection sign, not a union sign. It makes more sense now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: @bof Very helpfull, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guide:
Try to deduce the relationship usign the following equalities.
\begin{align}
P(E \cup F) &= P(E \cap F)+P(E \cap F^c)+P(F\cap E^c)\\
P(E) &= P(E \cap F)+P(E\cap F^c)\\
P(F)&= P(E \cap F)+P(F \cap E^c)
\end{align}